# How to create a named pipe "file" in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How do you create a named pipe in Java in Android Studio? My goal is once I have a named pipe write incoming video data to it. However, I have been looking around and cannot find information on how to initiate/create a named pipe on Android Studio Java.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @PPartisan I have not found a solution yet for implementing it in Android Studio.

Comment: I was able to crate a named pipe in native code and read it in my application, if that helps

Comment: Yeah I could try it if you are willing to share the code

Comment: Honestly, I can't remember the exact steps right now. But, if you follow the NDK documentation for integrating native code into your app, you can use `mkfifo()` to create a named pipe, and then in your application, read it in Java code by using a `FileInputStream` on a file pointing to the pipe's location. This is working very well for me now - data is written to the pipe in native code, and read in the app.